# kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (0) Reason: Handshake status 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to run a project on kubernetes local 2-node cluster instead of AWS cluster as in (https://github.com/hydro-project/cluster/blob/master/docs/getting-started-aws.md). But at some point in the installation script, I am getting this error. What could be the reason? Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py", line 468, in websocket_call
    client = WSClient(configuration, url, headers, capture_all)
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.sock = create_websocket(configuration, url, headers)
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py", line 452, in create_websocket
    websocket.connect(url, header=header)
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 252, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_handshake.py", line 59, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_handshake.py", line 145, in _get_resp_headers
    raise WebSocketBadStatusException("Handshake status %d %s", status, status_message, resp_headers)
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 500 Internal Server Error
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/akazad/hydro-project/cluster/hydro/cluster/create_cluster.py", line 245, in <module>
    args.conf, args.sshkey, cluster_name)
  File "/home/akazad/hydro-project/cluster/hydro/cluster/create_cluster.py", line 120, in create_cluster
    batch_add_nodes(client, apps_client, cfile, ['routing'], [route_count], BATCH_SIZE, prefix)
  File "/home/akazad/hydro-project/cluster/hydro/cluster/add_nodes.py", line 143, in batch_add_nodes
    add_nodes(client, apps_client, cfile, node_types, node_counts, True,prefix)
  File "/home/akazad/hydro-project/cluster/hydro/cluster/add_nodes.py", line 128, in add_nodes
    '/hydro/anna/conf/', cname)
  File "/home/akazad/hydro-project/cluster/hydro/shared/util.py", line 140, in copy_file_to_pod
    _preload_content=False, container=container)
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/stream.py", line 35, in _websocket_request
    return api_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 994, in connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec
    return self.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec_with_http_info(name, namespace, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 1115, in connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec_with_http_info
    collection_formats=collection_formats)
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 353, in call_api
    _preload_content, _request_timeout, _host)
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 184, in __call_api
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
  File "/home/akazad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py", line 474, in websocket_call
    raise ApiException(status=0, reason=str(e))
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (0)
Reason: Handshake status 500 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Check if you are using python version 3 or above. after upgrade python this issue pops-up. Please downgrade and check once

Comment: Looks like your python client is unable to establish a secure connection to a WebSocket. The server may be using a Self Signed Certificate or you may need to import the server certificate to your trust. Alternatively, you may choose to disable SSL verification for testing purposes.

Comment: None of these solutions worked. python version 3.6 is ok for this project. What do you mean by disable SSL verification? @RakeshGupta. I am just running it on locally set up 2-node kubernetes  cluster. Thanks by the way.

Comment: I haven't gone through these install instructions, but i've recently hit this same error.  In my case it was because the k8s api object I was trying to establish a connection to (a pod) wasn't ready to accept the connection.